# Is there an API for rendering OpenStreetMap data from PostgreSQL database?

Tags: android, postgresql, rendering, openstreetmap, postgis

I have setup a local **PostgreSQL** database with **PostGIS** extension and imported a .osm file into the database using osm2pgsql.

Now I want to display selected data on my Android client.

Via SQL statements I can now select data from the database, but I do not want to do the rendering myself. I want to specify the data that is taken from the database and then have it rendered to look like Google Maps.

Are there any Android APIs or Libraries that support the rendering of OSM-data coming from a database? Or do I need to to the rendering / drawing myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return geoJSON and use a javascript library like [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html) or [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) (others available). Typically though you would render the base layers server-side and deliver bitmaps, then use this for overlays.